# cannot append tuple onto list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
def enrollments(db : {str:{(str,str)}}) -> [(str,int)]:
    for node, value in db.items():
        lst=[] 
        lst.append((node, len(value)))
    print(lst)
```

The function tries to read a dictionary and return a two tuple list that contains the name of the key and the number of the values within the key. But when I run it, it shows:

```
enrollments({'ICS-31': {('Bob', 'A'), ('David', 'C'), ('Carol', 'B')}, 
             'Math-3A': {('Bob', 'B'), ('Alice', 'A')}
            })

[('Math-3A', 2)]
```

Were have I gone wrong?

Comment: `lst` need to be defined before the `for` loop.

Comment: So it should be [('ICS-31',3),('Math-3A', 2)], but there is only one element in the list

Comment: Failing to see the duplicate here. This is a question about reassigning a variable inside a loop. The alleged duplicate is about forgetting "return" when calling recursively. That doesn't seem like the same question to me.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Whoops, misread the question. My bad. Happens every now and then. Although there is a dupe for this too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reassigning the `lst` variable to an empty `list` every iteration. Assign it once, *before* the loop:

```
lst = [] 
for node, value in db.items():
    lst.append((node, len(value)))
```

You can also use a comprehension and avoid the issue altogether:

```
lst = [(node, len(value)) for node, value in db.items()]
```

The issue of returning `None` will be resolved by *actually* returning something:

```
def enrollments(db : {str:{(str,str)}}) -> [(str,int)]:
    return [(node, len(value)) for node, value in db.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

- You actually don't even need to use .items(), you can simply do the following:

  ```
  def enrollments(dictionary):
      _return_list_ = []
      for node in dictionary:
          _return_list_.append((node,len(dictionary[node])))
      return _return_list_
  ```